# google maps places is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am having a bit of an issue with trying to use google maps in my node application. I have the map loading and getting my location so far. I am trying to implement google code so I can allow users to search and local places appear. I am using the code from the google API page and have run into an issue. When I run the code its returns "google.maps.places is undefined". I have been looking all morning for the issue and can seem to fix it. Below is the code, thanks in advance!

```
function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
        zoom:16,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    //GEOLOCATION START
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
//GEOLOCATION END

//PLACES START
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
});

var markers = [];
// Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
// more details for that place.
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlace();

    if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }
        var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
]);
```

For anyone wonder aswell I have this on the page that the map loads on. I have my API key on the actual page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=......&sensor=false&callback=initializeMap&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Is your initialisation code waiting for the Google Api JS to load? e.g. running the initialize function on document ready event, not just in the body of the page. Otherwise it's a race condition as to which one happens first.

Comment: where do you have the `initializeMap` callback that you specified in script tag? All the actions requiring google should be in it otherwise, you will execute code before google is loaded, does that makes sense?

Comment: I have the map being called when the page is initialized. So im calling ng-init = "initialize()"

Answer (score 0):

For AngularJS i am using the [GoogleMapAPI](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api).
In the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/GoogleMapApi) you can see that you have to wait until the api has been fully initialized.

I think that you have the same problem but with this approach you can solve it at an higher level.

Hope this could help you

Comment: The map is appearing fine its just the search bar is not working.